# Input string was not in a correct format asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am getting this error don`t know why...

**here is Code (values in comments)..**

```
protected void FormView1_ItemCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {

            dsServicesTableAdapters.Select_NegotiateTableAdapter obj = new dsServicesTableAdapters.Select_NegotiateTableAdapter();

      //here i am getting the input string is not in a correct format error
            obj.Insert_Negotiate_New(Int32.Parse(stockid), //1
                Decimal.Parse(txtfobcustomer.Text),  //10
                Decimal.Parse(txtfrieghtcustomer.Text), //10
                Decimal.Parse(txtvanningcustomer.Text), //10
                Decimal.Parse(txtinspectioncustomer.Text), //10
                Decimal.Parse(txttotal_costcustomer.Text), //10
                Int32.Parse(ddlCurrency.SelectedValue), //  0.0105   
                Int32.Parse(ddlcountry.SelectedValue), //5 
                Int32.Parse(customerid),//1
                txtcustomername.Text, // Anglo  
                txtcustomerEmail.Text, // Anglo@computers.com  
                txtcustomer_phone.Text, // 03313752499  
                txtComments.Text, //test
                Int32.Parse(ddlshipmenttye.SelectedValue)); //2

        }
    }
```

**and here is my stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert_Negotiate_New]
(

    @stock_ID int,
    @client_FOB_Price money,
    @Client_FrieghtPrice money,
    @Client_Vanning_Price money,
    @Client_Inspection_Price money,
    @Client_Total_Cost money,
    @Currency_ID int,
    @Country_ID int,
    @Customer_ID int,
    @Client_Name varchar(50),
    @Client_Email varchar(50),
    @Client_Phone varchar(50),
    @Client_Comments varchar(3000),
    @ShipmentType int
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;


declare @negotiation_ID int
set dateformat dmy


Begin---insert negotiation

SELECT @negotiation_ID=ISNULL(MAX(negtiation_ID),0)+1 FROM negotiate


INSERT INTO negotiate (negtiation_ID,Time_Stamp, stock_ID,client_FOB_Price, Client_FrieghtPrice, Client_Vanning_Price,
 Client_Inspection_Price, Client_Total_Cost, Currency_ID,Country_ID,
  Customer_ID, Client_Name, Client_Email, Client_Phone, Client_Comments, ShipmentType) 
  VALUES (@negotiation_ID,GETDATE(),@stock_ID, @client_FOB_Price, @Client_FrieghtPrice, @Client_Vanning_Price,
   @Client_Inspection_Price, @Client_Total_Cost, @Currency_ID, @Country_ID,@Customer_ID, 
   @Client_Name, @Client_Email, @Client_Phone, @Client_Comments, @ShipmentType);

End
```

**Table**

[image: here is my Negotiate talbe]

Any Idea why i am getting this error although i am guessing that there are correct values

Comment: How sure are you that `ddlshipmenttye.SelectedValue` is 2? Could it be `"2 "`? (ie. with a space) And that goes for all the other parse calls as well. How sure are you that all of those will work?

Comment: Also, what is this? `Int32.Parse(ddlCurrency.SelectedValue), //  0.0105` Is `0.0105` the value in that field? Then why are you trying to parse it as an *int*? You should create validation to handle this sort of thing if that is the case, but my guess is that you wanted to use `decimal.Parse` instead.

Comment: hi @LasseV.Karlsen i am sure there is no space i have checked it in debugger

Comment: yes LasseV.karlsen it was ddlCurrency.SelectedValue thanks

Comment: Btw, here you see a good reason to use variables with meaningful names instead of passing the parameters directly from the control. That makes it also easier to debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int32.Parse(...)` or `Decimal.Parse(...)` throws the exception. The first and only i see is:

```
Int32.Parse(ddlCurrency.SelectedValue), //  0.0105
```

This is clearly not an `int` so use

```
Decimal.Parse(ddlCurrency.SelectedValue), //  0.0105
```

However, in your stored-procedure this seems to be also an `int` because it's a currency-ID. Then you have to fix this bug. The `DropDownList.SelectedValue` should not be `0.0105` when it's an int-ID.

Apart from that you would also get the exception if your current culture is not using the dot `.` as decimal separator. Then you have to enforce this separator by using `InvariantCulture`:

```
Decimal.Parse(ddlCurrency.SelectedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using Int32.Parse for parsing value like 0.0105. As you know this is not 
 an integer value so it will throw an exception. One more thing as I can see here you
 are using int for @Currency_ID int. It should be also money or decimal.

Comment: `Currency_ID` sounds as if it's a foreign key to a currency-table so money or decimal would be inappropriate. The prices are already money but other columns.